# prevent sql injection on query with variable (and large) number of columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I have a sql query that is generated using php. It returns the surrogate key of any record that has fields matching the search term as well as any record that has related records in other tables matching the search term.

I join the tables into one then use a separate function to retrieve a list of the columns contained in the tables (I want to allow additions to tables without re-writing php code to lower ongoing maintenance).

Then use this code

```
foreach ($col_array as $cur_col) {
    foreach ($search_terms_array as $term_searching) {
        $qry_string.="UPPER(";
        $qry_string.=$cur_col;
        $qry_string.=") like '%";
        $qry_string.=strtoupper($term_searching);
        $qry_string.="%' or ";
    }
}
```

To generate the rest of the query string

```
select tbl_sub_model.sub_model_sk from tbl_sub_model inner join [about 10 other tables]

    where [much code removed] or UPPER(tbl_model.image_id) like '%HONDA%' or
 UPPER(tbl_model.image_id) like '%ACCORD%' or UPPER(tbl_badge.sub_model_sk) like '%HONDA%'
 or UPPER(tbl_badge.sub_model_sk) like '%ACCORD%' or UPPER(tbl_badge.badge) like '%HONDA%'
 or UPPER(tbl_badge.badge) like '%ACCORD%' group by tbl_sub_model.sub_model_sk
```

It does what I want it to do however it is vulnerable to sql injection. I have been replacing my mysql_* code with pdo to prevent that but how I'm going to secure this one is beyond me.

So my question is, how do I search all these tables in a secure fashion?

Comment: You can use placeholders for like operators `LIKE ?` and then supply `"%{$searchterm}%"` as bound parameter.

Comment: how do I go about that? I was under the impression pdo took a fixed number of parameters. can I make one parameter apply to all instances of a question mark?

Comment: No, add one question mark for each occurence, then supply the search/like parameter multiple times. Alternatively keep your construction method and use `$pdo->quote()` instead.

Comment: problem is the number of occurrences is unknown till the code is run. it gets a list of the columns in the tables it wants to search and builds the query with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that asks the database to uppercase the search terms and also to adorn them with `'%'` wildcards:

```
$parameters = array();
$conditions = array();
foreach ($col_array as $cur_col) {
    foreach ($search_terms_array as $term_searching) {
        $conditions[] = "UPPER( $cur_col ) LIKE CONCAT('%', UPPER(?), '%')";
        $parameters[] = $term_searching;
    }
}

$STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT fields FROM tbl WHERE ' . implode(' OR ', $conditions));
$STH->execute($parameters);
```

**Notes:**

1. We let MySQL call UPPER() on the user's search term, rather than having PHP call strtoupper()
   That should limit possible hilarious/confounding mismatched character set issues.  All your normalization happens in one place, and as close as possible to the moment of use.
2. CONCAT() is MySQL-specific
   However, as you tagged the question `[mysql]`, that's probably not an issue.
3. This query, like your original query, will defy indexing.

Comment: @davidstrachan, please look again.  (Did you downvote?)  I do not use `'%?%'`.  The user's parameters are bound to an unquoted `?`, and then *the query engine itself* uppercases and concatenates wildcard characters.

Comment: `CONCAT('%', UPPER(?), '%'` == '%?%'. CONCAT Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: @davidstrachan, not quite.  The `?` is a *parameter placeholder* which is replaced by the user-supplied parameter *before* the UPPER() and *before* the CONCAT().  (Without execute-time parameter binding, the statement is a syntax error, _not_ a string concatenation.)

Comment: @davidstrachan, I know!  You are missing an important difference between the technique you cite, and the technique I actually use.  Please see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c203/2), and *please* pay attention to which question marks appear inside string literals and which do not. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this using an array to hold parameters. Notice % is added before and after term as **LIKE %?% does not work in query string**.[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#99698)

```
    //Create array to hold $term_searching
    $data = array();
    foreach ($col_array as $cur_col) {
        foreach ($search_terms_array as $term_searching) {
            $item = "%".strtoupper($term_searching)."%";//LIKE %?% does not work
            array_push($data,$item) 
            $qry_string.="UPPER(";
            $qry_string.=$cur_col;
            $qry_string.=") LIKE ? OR";
        }
}
$qry_string = substr($qry_string, 0, -3);//Added to remove last OR

$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT fields FROM table WHERE ". $qry_string);//prepare added 
$STH->execute($data);
```

**EDIT**

`$qry_string = substr($qry_string, 0, -3)` added to remove last occurrence of **OR** and `prepare` added to `$STH = $DBH->prepare("SElECT fields FROM table WHERE". $qry_string)`

Comment: You aren't preparing anything, `%?%` won't work, but `?` with `%VALUE%` bound to it will.